# How to get JournalEntryLine items from Netsuite ODBC

Tags: sql, odbc, netsuite

I am new to NetSuite and currently trying to query it via CData's ODBC driver for NetSuite.

According to the NetSuite schema browser (https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_1/schema/other/journalentryline.html?mode=package) there is an entity called JournalEntryLine that exists in Netsuite, I can see these line items listed in the Netsuite UI when i look up Journal Entries, however according to CData's docs (and my own investigation connecting via their ODBC driver, or directly via the SOAP API) I can only see a table called JournalEntry

I need to access this data but a query like SELECT * FROM JournalEntryLine gives me the following error: "[500] Could not execute the specified command: A table could not be found that matches JournalEntryLine"

Aware this is probably a stupid and basic question, but what *is* a JournalEntryLine in terms of netsuite's underlying data structure, and how do i extract it over an ODBC connection

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the Connect Browser gets you closer to what you can query with ODBC. The Schema Browser is for SOAP and (I think) REST web services.

In this case you are looking for Transactions and Transaction_lines